# Why does my cat cry outside the window when it is open enough for her to come inside?

Tags: cats, vocalizations

I live in a ground floor flat. My cat has demonstrated that she is well able to come and go through any open window in my flat - even the high one at the top of the window frame. Sometimes, however, she will sit (or lay) on the ground just outside the living room window and cry for attention. If I go all the way outside, she generally bolts inside. If I go to the window and get her attention she just continues to cry at me.

She knows how to come back in so what is she asking for?

Comment: Mating instinct, perhaps? Has she been spayed? Unfortunately, I have no experience with female cats, so I don't know if that will stop the behaviour.

Comment: Yes. She had the snip before I even got her.

Comment: if you go outside, what way did you cat use inside? And how are the windows open? real open, like a door, or in such a way, that their down side is connected to the frame and the opening looks like a "V"?